# OrderByDescending in EF doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi guys i have an model like this :

```
public partial class Path
{
    public Path()
    {
        this.Sensors = new HashSet<Sensor>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string StartStationId { get; set; }
    public string EndStationId { get; set; }
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public string Order { get; set; }

    public virtual Line Line { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to sort the list of this entity by the following code :

```
   List<Path> lstPath = _dbcontext.Paths.Where(i=>i.LineId==lineNumber).OrderByDescending(i => i.Order).ToList();
```

By the way i change it to this code :

```
List<Path> lstPath = _dbcontext.Paths.Where(i=>i.LineId==lineNumber).ToList();
       lstPath = lstPath.OrderByDescending(i => i.Order).ToList();
```

But it doesn't sort the list based on order column !!!why ?

Best regards

Comment: What does `Order` look like?  What order are you seeing and what are you expecting?

Comment: What does an example `Order` value look like? Is it a number that's stored as a string? Chances are you are sorting alphabetically instead of numerically, and may need to convert it first: `lstPath.OrderByDescending(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Order))`

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means.  What, specifically, goes wrong?  You're telling it to do something entirely different, namely sort an in-memory list rather than asking the database to sort the data, and the two can define "sorting" differently, but they will both "work".

Comment: Yes it is a number that is stored as a string

Comment: @EA Then that's your problem.  Store the number as a number, don't store it as a string, and your problems will all go away.

Comment: @EA: Check if your results are ordered alphabetically (e.g. 1, 10, 100, 2, 3, 31, 314, etc.). If they are try my suggestion a few comments up.

Comment: @Cory That requires the sorting to be done in memory in the application, not on the DB side of things, adds unnecessary overhead, and is simply conceptually wrong.  Storing integer data as a string is inherently a bad idea and should be fixed by storing it as an integer.

Comment: @Servy: I realize that now; I have retracted my suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing a number as a string, chances are you are sorting alphabetically instead of numerically, e.g.:

```
1
10
11
2
3
...
```

The right thing to do would be to change your model so that `Order` is a numeric type, because:

1. Storing numeric data as strings is inherently bad design
2. You will have a model that actually matches your data source
3. You take the guesswork out of sorting your data ("Order" is not a mystery value)

**EDIT:** I removed a previous suggestipn to convert the `Order` property to an `Integer` in the `OrderByDescending` lambda expression, but Entity Framework cannot perform that action against the database so it would require the overhead of sorting the data in memory.

Comment: After executing i got this error :LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @EA You can only use `Convert.ToInt32` in memory, i.e. after calling `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g yes i need to sort the values in memory

Comment: It works @Cory,it was my fault for executing :D